# Computer Guess Game JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple "guess the number game" in a web page where a user is the one thinking of the number and the computer is to guess the number that the user is thinking (no user input required). I need to create three buttons for user  to respond to the computer's guess: Guess Higher, Guess Lower, Correct. I am not sure how to make the GuessHigher() and GuessLower() function work. Here is the java script code:

```
function getFieldValue(target) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(target);
    var val = parseInt(elm.value);
    return val;
}

function getCompGuess() {
    var upper = getFieldValue("UPPER");
    var lower = getFieldValue("LOWER");

    return (parseInt((upper + lower) / 2))
}


/* User starts game. */
function play() {
    var remaining = getFieldValue("REMAINING");

    var compGuess = getCompGuess()
    var compElm = document.getElementById("COMP_GUESS")

    compElm.innerHTML = compGuess
}

function GuessHigher() {

}

function GuessLower() {

}

function correct() {
    alert ("YAY! Thank you for playing");   
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>

    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <script src="lab1a.js"></script>
    </head> 
<body>
Guess a number game: <br/> <br/>

Upper Bound: <input id="UPPER"  type="text"></input> <br/>
Lower Bound: <input id="LOWER" type="text"></input> <br/>
Guesses Remaining: <input id="REMAINING" type="text"></input> <br/>

<button onclick="play()">Play!</button>  <br/>

Computer's Guess: <span id="COMP_GUESS"></span> <br/>

<button onclick="GuessHigher()">Guess Higher</button>
<button onclick="GuessHigher()">Guess Lower</button>
<button onclick="correct()">Correct!!!</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Guess High" and "Guess Low" should update the Upper and Lower bounds *used for subsequent guesses*, respectively. While the field values themselves can be updated, this could also be done with variables to 'leave the original field values alone'.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The bounds are `[lower, upper]`. Currently these are read from field values. For instance, if the bounds are `[0, 10]` and the guess is 5 and the user says "too high" then then next guess is bounded by `[0, 4]`. The next guess is 2 and the user says "too low", then the bounds are `[3,4]`, etc..

Comment: Can you please provide me a solution so that I can understand better? Much appreciated.

Comment: *You* need to come up with a way such that each time a guess is made, it is done with updated `[lower,upper]` bounds, based on the previous user feedback - right now the bounds are read from the text fields (which are never changed by the guessing code). One method would be to *update* the text fields with the refined bounds (if this is acceptable/desired depends on external requirements). The algorithm is worked through a few steps above.

Comment: This question must be on a homework assignment at a big college or something.  It's the 3rd time I've seen it this week.

Answer (score 0):

GUESS HIGHER: 
It might not be elegant, but you could try to take the number last guessed and ADD to it any number within difference of UPPER BOUND-LAST GUESS. For example, lets say we have a number line with UPPER=10 and LOWER=0

0|----------|10

and we guess 5 as the computer. Now, if we want to guess higher we're going to need a place holder for our OLD Guess (5), and were going to need to decrease the guessing range so we don't go over our Upper boundry.

0|----<5>----|10, Imagine zooming in on only the top half 5>---10:

5>----|10. 
This new range I called availableGuessingRange which is equal to 10-5 or 5.

We're only going to let the computer pick a new number between 1 and 5 now using Math.random.

Let's say it picks 3. Now we can bring that number back to our old guess by adding it (ie. 5+3=8), now 8 is the computers NEW GUESS.

I think it could be something like this:

```
var lastGuess=document.getElementById("COMP_GUESS").value
var avaliableGuessingRange = upper-lastGuess;
return Math.floor(Math.random()*avaliableGuessingRange)+lastGuess
```

for GUESS LOWER: I think it would be a similar set up except it uses lastGuess-lower to create the new range and you'll be subtracting the new guess from the last guess to move DOWN the number line.

The way I've written the code currently won't work because of variable scopes, but I think the logic should work.

Comment: That is what i am exactly about to do. I will code after a while and I will let u know how it goes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I made fiddle out of this, and refactor the code tini little bit, inline listeners are considered bad practice. You should consider using some linter as there was some syntax error, mainly you were not terminating your statements; **<--- See, this was typo actually, I terminated the sentence accidently with ; instead of .**

```js
(function() {
  //getting references to buttons
  var high = document.getElementById('high');
  var lower = document.getElementById('lower');
  var btn_correct = document.getElementById('correct');

  //setting listeners
  high.addEventListener('click', GuessHigher);
  lower.addEventListener('click', GuessLower);
  btn_correct.addEventListener("click", correct);

  function getFieldValue(target) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(target);
    return parseInt(elm.value);
  }

  function getCompGuess() {
    var upper = getFieldValue("UPPER");
    var lower = getFieldValue("LOWER");

    return (parseInt((upper + lower) / 2));
  }


  /* User starts game. */
  function play() {
    var remaining = getFieldValue("REMAINING");

    var compGuess = getCompGuess();
    var compElm = document.getElementById("COMP_GUESS");

    compElm.innerHTML = compGuess;
  }

  function GuessHigher() {
    console.log('higher');
  }

  function GuessLower() {
    console.log('lower');
  }

  function correct() {
    console.log("YAY! Thank you for playing");
  }
}());
```

```html
<body>
  Guess a number game:
  <br/>
  <br/>Upper Bound:
  <input id="UPPER" type="text">
  <br/>Lower Bound:
  <input id="LOWER" type="text">
  <br/>Guesses Remaining:
  <input id="REMAINING" type="text">
  <br/>

  <button id='play'>Play!</button>
  <br/>Computer's Guess: <span id="COMP_GUESS"></span>
  <br/>

  <button id='high'>Guess Higher</button>
  <button id='lower'>Guess Lower</button>
  <button id='correct'>Correct!!!</button>

</body>
```

Comment: No, I was just concentrating on some syntax stuff, probably I would finish it up, but I found confusing your explanation and not congruent with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using code below

```
 Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) // return a number between 0 and 1000
```

to generate random numbers
And use if else statements for
High, low , correct